# Instrução Jquery que retorna o last child de elementos diferentes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá, estou fazendo uns exercícios de um curso de programação que fiz.
Me deparei com esta tarefa e não sei como resolve-la, alguém tem alguma dica?

Faça uma instrução jQuery que selecione todos os elementos que são os últimos filhos no HTML do tipo img OU que são os últimos filhos no HTML do tipo h3

Answer (score 2):

Para selecionar mais de um elemento no jquery, basta passar outros filtros no seletor utilizando a vírgula, por exemplo para selecionar a última imagem e o último H3 na página eu posso chamar da seguinte forma:

```
var lastBandImageAndName = $('img:last, h3:last');
```

Se eu quiser pegar todos os últimos elementos dentro de uma div, usando o mesmo exemplo acima:

```
var lastBandImageAndName = $('div img:last, div h3:last');
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var lastBandImageAndName = $('img:last, h3:last');

    lastBandImageAndName.each(function()
    {
       var tag = $(this).prop('tagName');
       if(tag === 'IMG')
       {
          $('#result').append('Última imagem URL = '+ $(this).prop('src'));
       }
       else if(tag === 'H3')
       { 
          $('#result').append('Último H3 texto = ' +  $(this).text());  
       }    
    });  
});
```

Eu criei um Fiddle com o código acima, se quiser dá uma olhada >> https://jsfiddle.net/h01gL4a1/